# Additional nested IIF

Tags: reporting-services

I'm really hoping someone can help with this, I'm not really hot on the finer points of SSRS and I'm struggling to find any articles that answer my query, or at least point me in the right direction.

I am trying to write an report that looks at the grades a student gets for each unit they take, change this from a "D" or "M' etc... to a value; 1 or 2 etc... and then gives me the average based upon the number of units they completed.

I've managed to get this far, but I now need to output a field that shows if the average value is between 1.0 and 1.5 display "Pass", between 1.6 and 2.5 display "Merit" and between 2.6 and 3.0 display "Distinction".

This is where I've got thus far:

```
  =SUM(IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="D",3,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="M",2,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="P",1,0))))/Fields!CompletedUnits.Value
```

I think I may need another IIF in front of the SUM, but I'm really not too sure.
Any help would be massively appreciated

Thanks
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this expression:

```
=Switch(
   (SUM(IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="D",3,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="M",2,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="P",1,0)))) /
   Fields!CompletedUnits.Value) > 2.6, "Distinction",
   (SUM(IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="D",3,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="M",2,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="P",1,0)))) /
   Fields!CompletedUnits.Value) > 1.5, "Merit",
   (SUM(IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="D",3,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="M",2,IIF(Fields!ActualGrade.Value="P",1,0)))) /
   Fields!CompletedUnits.Value) > 0.9, "Pass",
   true,"Nothing"
)
```

Also if you want to show the average in a column and the determined string (Metir, Pass, and Distinction) you can reference the text value by doing someting like this:

```
=Switch(
   ReportItems!TextBox14.Value > 2.6, "Distinction",
   ReportItems!TextBox14.Value > 1.5, "Merit",
   ReportItems!TextBox14.Value > 0.9, "Pass",
   true,"Nothing"
)
```

Where `TextBox14` is the textbox where you put the `Sum(IIF(...))/YouField` expression.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is absolutely spot on for what I needed!